# SSMS able to connect with localhost\foo, but not with just localhost

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to connect to localhost, but it won't let me.
Using localhost\foo or foo\foo does work.
SQL server is running, TCI/IP and Named Pipes are enabled.
I added a new rule to firewall for ssms on port 1433.
I also added an alias in server configuration manager.
What other options can I try?

Comment: If your SQL instance is a "named instance", then the instance name must be specified (with `\foo`). Do you have both a named and an unnamed instance installed? (Go to Services and scroll down to the `SQL Server` entries to validate) It is possible to [redirect](https://kohera.be/nl/blog/sql-server-nl/make-named-instance-look-like-default-instance/) the default instance to a named instance.

Comment: If you have a named instance, you need to supply the name in the connect string. If you don't want the name at the end, then you would need to create a new instance without the name (and use the default name) and then `RESTORE` your databases to that, along with migrating any of your `LOGIN`, `USERS`, etc.

Comment: Thank you,the redirect solved the issue @Sander

Comment: @jodeke You (or more likely someone else) may regret that choice later since it will confuse anyone trying to access the default instance if one is ever installed.